# MySQL crazy (?) floating point behavior

Tags: mysql, floating-point, floating-accuracy

On MySQL 8.0.21, I have an empty table (`Tbl`) with a single column: `num`, of type `float`.

I insert a single line, with the value `0.1`:

```
INSERT INTO Tbl(num) VALUES(0.1)
```

I run the following query and get the expected value `0.1`:

```
SELECT MAX(num) FROM Tbl
```

Now, I run a query which I think is semantically equivalent to the first query, and get `0.10000000149011612`:

```
SELECT MAX(IF(TRUE, num, 0)) FROM Tbl
```

Interestingly, this behavior doesn't reproduce without `MAX`, i.e. the following returns `0.1`:

```
SELECT IF(TRUE, num, 0) FROM Tbl
```

I know that floating point numbers cannot always be represented accurately, and I understand why arithmetic operations can cause this sort of issue, but why should using this `IF` inside `MAX` make a difference?

Answer (score 2):

They return different types. When you use MAX(), it upsamples the float value to a double:

```
CREATE TABLE T_MAX AS SELECT MAX(IF(TRUE, num, 0)) AS max_num FROM Tbl;

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE T_MAX\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: T_MAX
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `T_MAX` (
  `max_num` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


CREATE TABLE T_IF AS SELECT IF(TRUE, num, 0) AS if_num FROM Tbl;

mysql> SHOW CREATE TABLE T_IF\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
       Table: T_IF
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `T_IF` (
  `if_num` float DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

We can do a cast from float to double without doing MAX() and see the same effect:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST(num AS DOUBLE) AS dblnum FROM TBL;
+---------------------+
| dblnum              |
+---------------------+
| 0.10000000149011612 |
+---------------------+
```

Note that if we make the original stored num a double, it doesn't need to do a conversion, so it doesn't change the representation.

```
CREATE TABLE TBL2 (num DOUBLE);

INSERT INTO TBL2 (num) VALUES (0.1);

SELECT MAX(IF(TRUE, num, 0)) AS num FROM TBL2;
+------+
| num  |
+------+
|  0.1 |
+------+
```

So it's the conversion of float to double that introduces the issue.

Comment: Nice, thanks! I also tried your method with `MAX(num)` (i.e. without the `IF`). Indeed it evaluated to float, so no double conversion. So `MAX(num)` gives float, and `IF(TRUE, num, 0)` gives float, but `MAX(IF(TRUE, num, 0))` gives double. Why?

Comment: I don't know for sure, we'd have to be experts at reading the code of MySQL. But I can guess that the optimizer can tell the difference between `MAX(<expression>)` and `MAX(<single column>)`.

Answer (score 0):

[Float and double](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/floating-point-types.html) can't be saved exactly, so you get fractals

To get rid of them you have two possibilites

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Tbl(num float(2,1))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Tbl(num) VALUES(0.1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT MAX(IF(TRUE, num, 0))   FROM Tbl
> ```
>
> ```
> | MAX(IF(TRUE, num, 0)) |
> | --------------------: |
> |                   0.1 |
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE Tbl2(num float)
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO Tbl2(num) VALUES(0.1)
> ```

> ```
> SELECT ROUND(MAX(IF(TRUE, num, 0)),1)   FROM Tbl2
> ```
>
> ```
> | ROUND(MAX(IF(TRUE, num, 0)),1) |
> | -----------------------------: |
> |                            0.1 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0327ba5850e90affab0bf8ca6c63eedf)*

In both cases you need to know exactly how many digits after the cpmma/point you need

Comment: Thanks! but why does adding the `IF` make a difference?

Comment: that is  because IF uses the internal representation of the number, as you see it in the many digits fratals, and doesn't interpret them again to 0.1. as explained the link, they didn't implement it , besides it  is deterministic and and explained

Comment: Note that nonstandard `FLOAT(M,D)` is deprecated in MySQL 8.0.17. One should use `DECIMAL` instead.

Comment: i know it is mentioned in the linked text, but here it is the fractals that count.

Answer (score 0):

This is perhaps a partial answer, or at least some insight into what might be happening here.  If we consider your second query:

```
SELECT MAX(IF(TRUE, num, 0)) FROM Tbl
```

Then it is likely that the way it is being evaluated is that the result from the call to `IF(...)` is being stored in some intermediate floating point variable.  That is, the result from the call to `IF()`, which we know will be the floating point value `0.1`, is being *assigned* to some other intermediate floating point variable.  The act of making the assignment can cause the precision to change.

Comment: I suppose that's possible, but if the `IF` itself causes assignment to an intermediate variable (supposedly of a slightly different type, so a conversion is needed, right? otherwise it's just a matter of cloning the bits..) - then why doesn't it happen when using `IF` without `MAX`?

Comment: @obe Your edit doesn't necessarily invalidate my answer (completely).  If an assignment is really happening with `IF`, then it means the value _might_ change, not that it is guaranteed to change (but...don't ever rely on floating point if you require exact arithmetic, instead use an exact type like `NUMERIC`).

Comment: Ok, thanks for looking into this. I may actually go to the source code a bit later to try to make sure, and will be happy to accept your answer if that's really what's happening there :)